# Jquery: ajaxForm not doing anything whilst having correct ID's (fiddle)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I want to submit the right form after clicking a certain submit button on a form.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div id="post_output_1">
<form id="form_1" action="inc/action.php" method="post">
    <input id="age" type="text" name="age" />
    <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
</div>

<div id="post_output_2">
<form id="form_2" action="inc/action.php" method="post">
    <input id="age" type="text" name="age" />
    <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
</div>
```

And here is my Jquery code:

```
$("form").submit(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var formId = this.id;
     var divId = $(this).closest("div").attr("id");
     alert('#' + formId);
     alert('#' + divId);
          $('#' + formId).ajaxForm(function (data) {
          $('#' + divId).html(data);
     });
 });
```

Here is a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ryz3tqzr/1/

Its not submitting the form into the div, however it is finding the correct attributes.
Does anyone know why and how to let the form be actually submitted? (I use Jquery 1.11.0 and jquery form plugin)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: Clarifying from @j08691: your input fields do not have unique IDs :) you appear to have grasped the idea of unique IDs with your divs and forms, but the rule applies to all elements, not just containers.

Comment: Guys thanks for the comments I will update this in my code also I did in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ryz3tqzr/2/, however still the forms are not being submitted. If you check the fiddle the alerts echo the right id's of the forms and divs that should be 'acting' on submit

Comment: @user3655413 The forms can't submit to `"inc/action.php"` while in JSFiddle. The service would need to define that path itself since it's hosting the document. It defines [`/echo/html/` and similar](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html) that you can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the documentation of that plugin properly, ajaxForm is binding an event handler to the submit event of a form.

Your code is adding this handler after the submit has already occured within your own submit event handler. Furthermore you add an `e.preventDefault();` so, even the second hit on the button won't execute the additional handler, but puts another one on the stack.

I've updated the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4cw02Lfq/) a bit.

```
$("form").submit(function (e) {
    //e.preventDefault();
    var formId = this.id;
    var divId = $(this).closest("div").attr("id");
    alert('#' + formId);
    alert('#' + divId);
});

$('#post_output_1').ajaxForm(function (data) {
        $('#post_output_1').html(data);
    });

$('#post_output_1').ajaxForm(function (data) {
        $('#post_output_1').html(data);
    });
```

Edited:
In order to have it more generic, you probably can add a class to your div's:

```
<div id="post_output_1" class="output">
<form id="form_1" action="inc/action.php" method="post">
    <input id="age" type="text" name="age" />
    <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
</div>

<div id="post_output_2"class="output">
<form id="form_2" action="inc/action.php" method="post">
    <input id="age" type="text" name="age" />
    <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
</div>
```

and then:

```
....
$(".output").each(function (index, value) {
    var that = this;
    $(that).ajaxForm(function (data) {
        // console.log(this);
        $(that).html(data);
    });
});
```

fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/z81obcqn/).

Comment: Thank you kindly for your answer. How would I solve something like this when I have aproximately 20 forms loaded (each having different ID's not starting at a specified number)? (I use this code to edit sql data, forms are generated by php) PS: you meant this fiddle right? : http://jsfiddle.net/ryz3tqzr/3/

Comment: I accepted your answer! However: do you know how to do this dynamically?